# Чрезмерное использование if else в скрипте инпута Unity 3D(C#). Страдает ли производительность?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть скрипт отвечающий за считывание клавиш с клавиатуры, проверяются 20 кнопок по очереди и соответственно в каждом if проверяется еще 10 условий:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && check_1 && !check_2 && check_3 && !check_4 && check_5 
        && !check_6 && !check_7 && check_8 && check_9 == null)
```

Если забыть о том что с таким кодом не удобно работать и добавлять новый функционал, насколько это будет сказываться на произодительности и будет ли провоцировать баги, неотзывчивость управления и т.д.?

Comment: Странный вопрос. Использование юнити означает, что на производительность уже положен болт в угоду простоте разработки. И десяток дополнительных логических операций в каком-то условии погоды не делают.

Comment: В плане производительности здесь проблем не так много, ибо в случае если левая часть `false`, то правая попросту не будет обрабатываться. А вот в плане багов... С таким кодом вы являетесь отличным генератором этих самых багов, ибо в нем ооочень легко запутаться, а не указав одну из проверок, или указав ее не так, весь ваш код идет не так, как вы это ожидаете. Поэтому тут вам больше стоит не о производительности думать, а о читаемости в первую очередь, например, сделать класс выполняющий одну проверку, заполнить коллекцию ими, и метод проверки, вариантов уйма по решению такого, не ленитесь.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вы попали в точку, этот код доставил неприятности, с которыми пришлось возиться несколько дней. Более подобным образом не пишу. Волнует лишь влияние на отзывчивость управления персонажем, особенно когда проэкт нагрузится другим функционалом. А переписывать займет изрядное количество времени.

Comment: Само наличие больших ифов это ошибка. Мухи отдельно, катлеты отдельно. Есть класс отвечающий за импуты и передающий персонажу параметры и команды. Если нажат пробел, вызывается команда прыгнуть и все, ничего не проверяется, все проверки типа стоит ли на земле происходят в самом методе, а не в классе импутов. Если двигаешь аналог или стрелки, передается вектор движения, будет ли он использоваться в данный момент, является головником того, кто двигается, даже если персонаж мертв, это не забота импутов. Читаемый код начинается с единственной и понятной ответственности класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество проверок можно уменьшить. Но производительность ифов - это не то, о чём стоит беспокоиться в первую очередь. Ифы очень быстрые. А вот читабельность кода может пострадать, и приёмов её обеспечить много: `switch-case`, коллекции, флаги и другие.

Один из способов сделать не только код читабельней, но и быстрее это - перечисление в качестве флагов. Но стоит помнить, что перечисление это набор констант, а значит с помощью ресурсов или других источников данных в него значений не добавить.

Просто покажу приём, а вы уж решайте сами, полезно или нет. Например, игрок может быть жив/мёртв, находиться на земле или нет. А чтобы прыгнуть, игрок одновременно должен быть на земле, быть живым, и например у него должен быть не перегружен рюкзак. Заведу перечисление.

```
[Flags]
public enum State
{
    None = 0,
    Alive = 1,
    OnGround = 2,
    NotOverloaded = 4
}
```

Флаги, это степени двойки 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 и т.д.

Чтобы изменить состояние, используется двоичная логика.

```
State state = State.None;
state |= State.Alive; // OR, вкл
state &= ~State.Alive; // AND NOT, выкл
state ^= State.Alive; // XOR, тоггл
```

Чтобы проверить, есть встроенная функция `HasFlag`

```
if (state.HasFlag(State.Alive))
{
    // игрок жив
}
```

Как же быть с комбинациями. А легко, с помощью той же двоичной арифметики.

```
State canJump = State.Alive | State.OnGround | State.NotOverloaded;
```

И проверить

```
if (state.HasFlag(canJump)) { ... }
```

А можно использовать константу вот так

```
[Flags]
public enum State
{
    None = 0,
    Alive = 1,
    OnGround = 2,
    NotOverloaded = 4,
    CanJump = Alive | OnGround | NotOverloaded // 1 + 2 + 4 = 7
}
```

```
if (state.HasFlag(State.CanJump)) { ... }
```

На самом деле, это эквивалент вот такой записи

```
if ((state & State.CanJump) == State.CanJump) { ... }
```

Итого, я проверяю 3 условия за одно сравнение. Точнее, за один двоичный AND и одно сравнение.

---

Но не гонитесь сильно за производительностью в ущерб читабельности кода, соблюдайте баланс.

Не ко всему выше показанный приём можно применить, и не везде он будет достаточно удобен, но освоить его стоит.

- [Документация HasFlag](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag)
- [Документация FlagsAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute)

---

Бонусом скажу, что перечисление, это число, по умолчанию `int`, а значит и сохранить его можно как число.

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerState", (int)state);
```

```
State state = (State)PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlayerState", 0);
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый и понятный ответ!

Answer (score -3):

Создавать баги в любом случаи будут. А по поводу оптимизации все хорошо. Но можно сделать лучше. В типе `short` есть 4 байта и того 32 битов. Это 32 `bool` типа данных. Воспользуйтесь лучше побитовыми сдвигами и проверками на биты.

К примеру:

```
class Example
{
    void Foo()
    {
        bool b1 = true;
        bool b2 = true;
        
        if (b1 && b2)
        {
            // TODO: implement
        }
    }
}
```

или:

```
class Example
{
    void Foo()
    {
        uint flag = 0;
        
        flag |= 1 << 0;
        flag |= 1 << 1;
        
        if ((flag & (1 << 0)) != 0 && (flag & (1 << 1)) != 0)
        {
            // TODO: implement
        }
    }
}
```

Да, писать нужно больше немного. Но так будет более правильно!

Comment: А вот и "экономию" на спичках подвезли...

Comment: `short` - это два байта, а не 4

Comment: Нет необходимости каждый бит отдельно проверять. Сразу на нужную маску умножайте и все.

Comment: @Grundy я знаю что там 2 байта, я правку сделал но что-то оно не сделалось. И, так как это ванючий C# такой метод не оптимизированный. В Си лучше нет, чем этот.